# Athena - Alter table cascade

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-athena, presto, cascade

I am trying to add some columns to the Athena table with Cascade using below:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD columns (c1 string, c2 string) CASCADE;
```

But this gives error in Athena. I have 2 questions:

1. Is Cascade not supported in Athena with Alter Table Add Columns?
2. Is there any option of IF NOT EXIST with ADD Columns?

Comment: What would an `ADD COLUMNS ... CASCADE` option do? Normally, Cascade is used when dropping columns/tables. What would it do when _adding_ columns?

Comment: This is w.r.t updating the partitions that have already been added to the table.

Comment: In Athena, adding columns merely changes the _definition_ of the table. It does not impact the contents of any data files. So, it will automatically apply to any existing partitions, but it is up to you to add the extra columns in the data files themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The [`ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMNS` documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/alter-table-add-columns.html) does *not* show a `CASCADE` option, nor an `IF NOT EXIST` option.

Comment: Yeah, I have gone through the documentation already and did not find anything. So, posted the question. Thanks